# How to record Adobe Photoshop Photomerge action?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to record a Photomerge action in Adobe Photoshop, so that I can re-use this action for batch photo merging. However I'm only able to record the first step of the Photomerge, i.e: Layout and Source File select window.

How can I also record subsequent actions for the Photomerge function? Such as layout select or photo sources?

Thank You!

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129272/how-to-record-adobe-photoshop-photomerge-action

Comment: It's a script, actions don't record script settings, they only run them. You'll need to make a copy of the photomwrge script with your settings